# Flutter Responsive Text Field Matching screen sizes

Tags: flutter, uitextfield, flutter-layout

Hello i was working on flutter in need to make my TextField responsive using MediaQuery which match all screen sizes.I have tried by two ways both not working for tablets here is the firstOne

```
Container(
                    height: 100.0,
                    width: 300.0,
                    child: TextField(
                      cursorColor: Colors.black,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.pinkAccent),
                      controller: itemNameController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Hello input here',
                        isDense: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 5, bottom: 11, top: 11, right: 5),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

the second way is

```
                           TextField(
                          cursorColor: Colors.black,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.pinkAccent, height: 
                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/50),
                          controller: itemNameController,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: 'Hello input here',
                            isDense: true,
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 5, bottom: 11, top: 11, right: 5),
                          ),
                        ),
```

both of them are not reflecting on Tablet. Thanks

Comment: Use the first implementation and set the width of container to double.infinity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a responsive class that resizes to the screen size. I implement this class in widget classes and give an int value according to the screen size. In this way, it resizes according to the size of the screen on each phone.

```
class SizeConfig{
    
  double heightSize(BuildContext context, double value){
    value /= 100;
    return MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * value;
  }

  double widthSize(BuildContext context,double value ){
    value /=100;
    return MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * value;
  }
}
```

You can use it like this;

```
Container(
                height: sizedConfig().heightSize(context, 2.0)
                width: sizedConfig().widthSize(context, 1.5),
                child: TextField(
                  cursorColor: Colors.black,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.pinkAccent),
                  controller: itemNameController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Hello input here',
                    isDense: true,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 5, bottom: 11, top: 11, right: 5),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: thanks all All are best but Mert Toptas answ was very good

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting MediaQuery for the height and width of the container that contains the TextField?

In your first way, height and width is fixed, so the size of TextField will not change.

In your second way, i believe "style" is used to change the style of the text inside TextField, not the TextField. Instead, use "decoration" if you want to change the appearance of TextField.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid SizeConfig(custom class) and hard coded dimensions as much as you can.
Example: `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - someValue`

Best easiest way to make responsive UI is [Sizer](https://pub.dev/packages/sizer) plugin.

Responsive UI in any screen size device also tablet.
Check it this plugin ⬇️
https://pub.dev/packages/sizer

```
.sp - for font size
.h  - for widget height
.w  - for widget width
```

If you want to set responsive Textfield size then use only `.w` for width and `.h` for height after value.

Example:

```
Container(
            height: 4.0.h    // 4% of screen height
            width: 80.0.w,   // 80% of screen width
            child: TextField(
              cursorColor: Colors.black,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.pinkAccent),
              controller: itemNameController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Hello input here',
                isDense: true,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 5.0.w, bottom: 1.0.h, top: 1.0.h, right: 5.0.w),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```