# Make UI fit the screen in dart on mobile view

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, mobile

I am building a registration. I built the page and here is a sample code block from that:

```
class RegistrationPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFB0C4DE),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 32.0),
              RegistrationField(
                label: 'Email',
                placeholder: 'Enter Email',
                isPassword: false,
              ),
              RegistrationField(
                label: 'Password *',
                placeholder: 'Enter Password',
                isPassword: true,
              ),
              RegistrationField(
                label: 'Re-enter Password *',
                placeholder: 'Re-enter Password',
                isPassword: true,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 32.0),
```

and another button and text down the line. It looks cut off at the bottom despite having more space to the bottom of the page.

[image]

How can I make the fields use the full page height? As you see in the picture, the button is not visible and therefore not clickable. I can't scroll down (I don't have a mouse just a mouse pad) and on a real build, I don't want it to look like this, I want it to fit the screen.

How can I somehow make all these elements fit and disable any kind of overflow to the bottom like in the picture?

Is there a way to set rule for auto-sizin so that it automatically fits the screen?

If this is not possible, how do I make it scrollable?

Comment: You'd better to make it scrollable because some devices are small and some devices are bigger.

Comment: is there a way to set rule for auto sizing ? 

so that it automatically fits the screen?

if this is not psosible how do I make it scrollable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64798834/21590733 use Sizer package

Comment: There are many ways to auto sizing your widgets. But this is not recommended because all the devices have different size and different pixel. And all of them will look different and you need to check all of theirs looking which is difficult. Instead, make it scrollable so that you don't need to worry about 'over size'.

Answer (score 2):

Just a reminder, displaying the entire page content full screen does not guarantee that all widgets will display as you expected, they may be broken to fit all on one screen.

Imagine you have 10 `RegistrationField`, and each `RegistrationField` height is 70px, meaning you need a device with a screen length greater than 700px. In case the device has a height of 400px, the 10 `RegistrationField` will be compressed to fit within the 400px available on the device.

And yes, you can set the `RegistrationField`'s height as percent based on the device's height to make it responsive, but think about it, isn't the `RegistrationField`'s height be set to super small (to fit 10 widgets in 400px height) and unable for the user to use?

Now, if you still want to make all widgets fit on one screen. Wrap `RegistrationField` by `Expand` widget, and remove the `SingleChildScrollView`.

Example for fit 30 Container in one screen:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: List.generate(30, (index) {
          return Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text((index + 1).toString(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    height: 50,
                  )));
        }),
      ),
    );
```

And the text doesn't even display fully. Good luck!
[image]